# Using simple JS to dynamically control parameters within this URL to control content size, fitting the screen

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

**Can I use some sort of JS script to take advantage of the size control here in the url**

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://media.embed.ly/1/frame?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitch.tv%2Fgamemode_mc_&amp;width=1280&amp;height=1280&amp;secure=true&amp;key=0202f0ddb5a3458aabf520e5ab790ab9&amp;"
```

**to dynamically force the size of the iframe content to match the user's browser window?
This will combine the solution to my original question with a secondary solution to provide the perfect fix for my problem here.**

*(My goal here is actually to place this Twitch feed as a background to my webpage - resizing the actual content of the iframe is actually a very unusual but additional treat here, because of the way Twitch's url works!)*

To be clear, I'm very early in my learning of JS, and looking for a beginner solution to take the browser window size to dynamically control the parameters in this url to control the size of the content in this iframe.

```
width=1280&amp;height=1280&amp;
```

are the key lines here. I need to make these measurements follow the viewport size instead of being static. What method is best to do this?

Comment: This is the third time I've posted this in a simpler format. No one answers this lol

Comment: Did my answer help? If yes, then please check it, if not, please provide an answer of your own and check that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I get your question right but changing the width and height parameters of your iframe can be done by this (used jquery for getting height and width of window cross browser)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var iframe = $("#myIframe");
    iframe.attr("width",$(window).width());
    iframe.attr("height",$(window).height());
});
```

Comment: Update my original post.